# DOMPDF: CSS being ignored

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I am generating a PDF document using DOMPDF.

The html that is being 'printed to PDF' renders as expected in a browser. 
However when using DOMPDF the CSS layout is ignored. Note: When using inline CSS `<td style="width:2cm;">` the document renders properly. The desired and resulting outputs are shown below. As is a snippet of the code that renders improperly.

Thanks,

Desired Output: 
[image: Desired Output]

DOMPDF Output: 
[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    td { 
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top; 
    }

    .num {
    width: 1cm;
    }

    .spc {
    width: 2cm;
    }

    .quanda {
    width: 8cm;
    }

</style>

<div>
    <h1>Demographics</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <hr/>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="num">1)</td>
                <td class="quanda">Study ID</td>
                <td class="spc"> </td>
                <td class="quanda">2349723</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="num">2)</td>
                <td class="quanda">Date subject signed consent</td>
                <td class="spc"> </td>
                <td class="quanda">12 March 2012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="num">3)</td>
                <td class="quanda">Upload the patient's consent form</td>
                <td class="spc"> </td>
                <td class="quanda">Uploaded: URL: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="num">4)</td>
                <td class="quanda">First Name</td>
                <td class="spc"> </td>
                <td class="quanda">Bob</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="num">5)</td>
                <td class="quanda">Last Name</td>
                <td class="spc"> </td>
                <td class="quanda">Dylan</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which release of dompdf? v0.6.0 (currently in beta) renders the code as expected. v0.5.x does not I think due to problems applying the styles (though I'd have to research the issue). However, we're not patching 0.5.x anymore and recommend using the latest posted version of v0.6.0 (currently beta 3).

Comment: Thanks BrainS. I am using V0.6.0 beta 3. I will try reinstall the package and see if that helps.

Comment: I sorted out the issue. It was on my side. Thanks for the support. Great project!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad you were able to sort it out.